# Disable Ctrl key simulation by Win Key in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I've got two AHK scripts running simultaneously.
First is:

```
#I::Run calc.exe
```

And second:

```
^I::Run notepad.exe
```

So, when I press Win + I to run first script, second script starting too, because WIN key simulates CTRL key. How to disable it? Without change keys.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're trying to say. Could you try to rephrase and show your whole script instead of just a few snippets?

Comment: Maybe now is better :)

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound right. I don't think the Win key should have anything to do with the ctrl key, unless you have some sort of a special setup. I'm also unable to reproduce your problem on my end. Is there anything else in the scripts that could cause this?

Comment: No. When I change keys in second script it's working fine.

Comment: was the problem actually solved? This sounded interesting to me and I'd like to know what caused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to open calculator with the first script and Notepad with the second, you forgot to put the `Run` command before `calc.exe` in the first script.

In other words, the reason that it appears that the first script does not function is not caused in any way by the second script, just change the code of the calculator script to:

```
#I::Run calc.exe
```

Comment: I don't think that's it, he probably just typod when editing the question. `#I:: calc.exe` doesn't do anything. It just tries to retrieve a property named `exe` in an object named `calc`.

Comment: Yes @0x464e, but the fact that calc.exe is a valid PATHed executable that can be opened with `run`, in combination with the fact that his second script also contains a `run` command, gives me the feeling that he just forgot to add that word when he was creating that hotkey. Ofc, if he later adds info that would clarify what he really wants, if it is different than this, you can go ahead and write a better answer for OP to accept. : )

Comment: The problem was about `^I` hotkey being triggered as well when `#I` was triggered. My point was that adding in `Run` shouldn't have any effect on that. And I don't know either what goes wrong for him. My best guess was in the comments above.

Comment: Fair enough, let us hope that OP gives us some more info about what's causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Forgot add Run.

Comment: In that case, could you please accept this answer @Hoshie so that others know that this question is resolved?